# integration of a nonnegative definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I wanted to know, whether the integration of a nonnegative definite matrix is again going to be a nonnegative definite matrix?
for example, if $A(t)$ is a nonnegative definite  $n\times n$ matrix, then what we can tell about $\int_{a}^{b} A(t) dt,$   where $t\in [a, b]$

Answer (score 4):

Yes, just take the product with $x^T$ on the left, $x$ on the right. Then
$$ x^T \left( \int_a^b A(t) dt \right) x =  \int_a^b\left(  x^T A(t)x \right) dt \geq 0$$
since the integrand is  positive (strictly if $A(t)$ is positive definite and $x\neq 0$).

Comment: thank you..this answer is useful